# Mechanically increasing RPM of ac induction motor

Tags: electrical-engineering, motors, ac

If you spin the stator of an AC induction motor than would the rotation of the rotor increase? Or would it have a different affect such as moving with a higher force?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A standard induction motor has to turn at the speed determined by the current frequency.  If you attempt to apply external torque to drive it faster it will act as a brake resisting that torque. 
If you apply sufficient torque to force the rotor out of phase with the driving current it would effectively stall ( the "braking force" dropping way off and or becoming erratic )

Comment: Does this answer the question?

Comment: @joojaa , yes it does.